# What Minimum Value Can I Measure With ACS712 30A Current Sensor?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am making an Arduino multimeter for current measurement. I first thought about using a shunt but that fails to work since I need to measure current in the mA range.

Answer (score 2):

That model has a sensitivity of 66mV/A which means for every 1A of current passing through it outputs 66mV.

The Arduino's ADC when running at 5V has a resolution of (5/1024) 4.88mV per LSB.

That means that 4.88/66 gives you 0.074 - or 74mA per LSB.

Since 1LSB is considered to be in the noise area of the signal you can expect the minimum usable value to be double that - 148mA

Which is pretty useless for measuring currents in the mA range.

You would get better results with the 5A variant, but still not great.

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet for the ACS712](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/0712.pdf) shows the following:

[image]

This means the 30A variant has a sensitivity of 66mV/A. This means a reading of 1A will show 66mV plus some bias voltage. The Arduino ADC is 10-bit, meaning it has 2^10 = 1024 increments across a default 5V voltage reference for the Uno, Nano, etc. This gives it a measuring resolution of 5V/1024 increments = 4.88mV voltage resolution. 4.88mV / 66mV/A = 0.074A, or 74mA.

So, the default *resolution* of an Arduino Uno, Nano, etc, is **74mA.** Realistically it will bounce around this value, so your *precision* might be about 3~4x this, or around **300mA**, and your accuracy is as good as you calibrate it, which could easily be around this value too if you calibrate it well.

74mA resolution isn't bad, but there are several tricks to improve this. Here are a few:

**1. External hardware solutions:**

1. **Use the 20A or 5A version instead of the 30A version of the ACS712.** The 5A version has a sensitivity of 185mV/A, which automatically improves your resolution to 4.88mV / 185mV/A = 0.026A, or **26mA**, which is 74mA/26mA = **2.8x better**.
2. **Buy an external ADC with high-resolution.** This [Adafruit ADS1115 16-Bit ADC](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1085) ([datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ads1115.pdf)) will improve your resolution on the 30A version of the ACS712 as follows. Minimum resolution of the ADC is now 5V/2^16 = 5V/65535 = 0.0763mV instead of 4.88mV, and 0.0763mV / 66mV/A = 0.001156A, or **1.156mA**.

**2. Software solutions (freebies!):**

1. **Change your voltage reference to use the internal 1.1V internal reference.** This is easy: call `analogReference(INTERNAL)` in your `setup()` function. Done! See: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogreference/. If I recall correctly, this is a diode-based internal voltage reference (see the ATmega328 datasheet), and can be off by as much as 10% from part to part, so calibrate it for each individual Arduino you have and you will get good results! Now, your ADC resolution is 1.1V/1024 = 1.07mV instead of the Arduino's default 4.88mV, so your current resolution is 1.07mV / 66mV/A = **16.2mA**, which is 74mA/16.2mA = **4.6x better**.
2. **Use oversampling to increase the Arduino's 10-bit ADC to up to ~16 bits or so.** Atmel Application Note [AVR121: Enhancing ADC resolution by oversampling](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/doc8003.pdf) explains this very well, albeit it requires some serious study. There are libraries which exist to do this for you which you can Google for. I wrote one of them. [Here is a link to my website where I present one such library I wrote](https://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/2014/05/using-arduino-unos-built-in-16-bit-adc.html). The gist is this: to get an 11-bit reading (which is 1-bit better than your hardware ADC resolution of 10-bits) you need to take 4^1 = 4 10-bit readings, sum them, then divide by 2^1 = 2. Your max value will be 1023 x 2 = 2046. To get a 16-bit reading (which is 6-bits better than your hardware ADC resolution of 10-bits) you need to take 4^6 = 4096 10-bit readings, sum them, and divide by 2^6 = 64. Your max value will be 1023 x 64 = 65472. Your voltage resolution will be improved from 4.88mV to ~0.0764mV *at best*. It won't be as good as a true 16-bit ADC, like the Adafruit one above, but it's good enough for many uses. Keep in mind that 4096 10-bit readings takes some time, so I also recommend you speed up the ADC clock to improve reading rate at 10-bits from ~10kHz to ~50kHz. This is also where a library comes in handy to make this easy to do. Free and open source solutions already exist. Here's a table I made back when I first read the  AVR121 application note and practiced oversampling. Consider the resolution values beyond ~16-bits to be purely theoretical. Oversampling has its limits.

   1. [image]

What would I do? I'd use the 1.1V internal voltage reference and oversampling with increased ADC clock speed on the ACS712 part which provides the minimum acceptable max current (ie: choose the 5A version not the 20A or 30A version if 5A is enough, or the 20A version not the 30A version if 20A is enough). **Just be sure that your max voltage now at the analog pins will not exceed the 1.1V Vref value**. If it will, use the standard 5V reference for the ADC, and just do oversampling alone. My current resolution would end up being a few mA in the end. If I can't sample at the desired frequency using oversampling (I don't know what dynamic effects you may be trying to measure), then I'd use an external high-resolution ADC which can sample faster than oversampling at high resolutions would allow.

---

And if that's not good enough, what would I do? I'd use a precision shunt, ie: "current resistor" with the right value such that I can measure values at the right range. If I need amplification I'd buy an external ADC and/or op-amp from Adafruit until I have everything sized just right. Remember, if your shunt (current resistor) is too small to measure the low currents you need, do the following:

1. Use a higher resistance value. V = IR (Voltage = Current x Resistance), so increase R to increase the V across it for a given current, I.
2. Use an op-amp to amplify the voltage drop across the resistor (go for an Adafruit one since Adafruit makes it easy and has the world's best examples).
3. Use a high-resolution ADC, and/or oversampling to increase your sensitivity to measure small voltage changes.

Comment: Thanks sir....  Thats actually helps 

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to click the up-arrow at the top-left of answers to upvote answers that you find helpful, and click the check-mark if you'd like to mark an answer as the "best" or "correct" answer. It helps bring the best answers to the top to help others after you who have the same question.